# label value is not showing for agm-marker in angular 7

Tags: angular7, angular-google-maps, agm-map

I am showing some markers using angular-google-map in angular 7.but label property  of marker is not showing the value.

```
 <agm-map [latitude]="lat" [longitude]="lng" [zoom]="zoom" [styles]="styles" [disableDefaultUI]="false" [zoomControl]="true"
[scrollwheel]="false" [streetViewControl]="false" [fitBounds]="false">

      <agm-marker *ngFor="let m of clusterData; let i = index" (markerClick)="clickedMarker(infowindow, i)" [latitude]="m.lat" [longitude]="m.lon" [label]="m.count">      
      </agm-marker>

  </agm-map>
```

m.count not showing the count inside markers label.

Comment: Answer found for this one? As if i am showing a fixed value from my ts file its working but if i am using ngfor and showing labels out of it then its not displaying the labels